# TLS fatal alert in wget

Tags: wget, tls, gnutls

I wanted to download a file, I would normally use wget for such an action, but it gives me a TLS error.

```
root@darren-hp:/var/www/html/adminer# wget "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/vrana/adminer/master/designs/price/adminer.css"
--2017-09-17 18:28:35--  https://raw.githubusercontent.com/vrana/adminer/master/designs/price/adminer.css
Resolving raw.githubusercontent.com (raw.githubusercontent.com)... 62.252.172.241
Connecting to raw.githubusercontent.com (raw.githubusercontent.com)|62.252.172.241|:443... connected.
GnuTLS: A TLS fatal alert has been received.
GnuTLS: received alert [0]: Close notify
Unable to establish SSL connection.
root@darren-hp:/var/www/html/adminer#
```

I tried with curl and it received the file without any problem

```
root@darren-hp:/var/www/html/adminer# curl "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/vrana/adminer/master/designs/price/adminer.css" > adminer.css
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100 21606  100 21606    0     0  72967      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:-- 72993
root@darren-hp:/var/www/html/adminer#
```

So my curiosity was sparked and I tried wget in debug mode, but I don't think the output gives any more information that is relevant

```
root@darren-hp:/var/www/html/adminer# wget -d "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/vrana/adminer/master/designs/price/adminer.css"
DEBUG output created by Wget 1.16 on linux-gnu.

URI encoding = ‘UTF-8’
--2017-09-17 18:30:14--  https://raw.githubusercontent.com/vrana/adminer/master/designs/price/adminer.css
Certificates loaded: 174
Resolving raw.githubusercontent.com (raw.githubusercontent.com)... 62.252.172.241
Caching raw.githubusercontent.com => 62.252.172.241
Connecting to raw.githubusercontent.com (raw.githubusercontent.com)|62.252.172.241|:443... connected.
Created socket 4.
Releasing 0x000000000178a9e0 (new refcount 1).
GnuTLS: A TLS fatal alert has been received.
GnuTLS: received alert [0]: Close notify
Closed fd 4
Unable to establish SSL connection.
root@darren-hp:/var/www/html/adminer#
```

I visited the file in my browser (Firefox 52.3.0esr) and it didn't offer any indication that there was any kind of problems with the certificate.
[image: Certificate]

To confirm it wasn't a problem at my end, I used wget to download a different file that was also on a server using TLS and it downloaded without any trouble.

After finally resorting to Google I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36832118/wget-over-ssl-gives-unable-to-establish-ssl-connection) thread that suggested what seemed like a similar problem. Apparently TLS 1.2 is only supported in wget from v1.16.1 and I am only running v1.16 so I tried `--check-no-certificate` and it made no difference.

### Question: Why does wget give me a TLS error in this case? What is the problem, and is it something I can solve? Should I notify the site owner?

Comment: Have you tried to upgrade the version of wget your using just for kicks and giggles?